# Creating a double quoted entry list from a de-limited string in Python

Tags: python, shell, powershell, awk

I have a line something like

`date |v3| 0.00| 0.00| 0.00| 0| 0| 7324.00| 0.00| 12278 12276|Tue Jan 29 09:36:47`

i want to iterate this line and form an output something like this

`["date" ,"v3" ,"0.00" ,"0.00" ,"0.00" ,"0" ,"0" ,"7324.00" ,"0.00" ,"12278 12276","Tue Jan 29 09:36:47"]`

this i want to achieve using the shell script, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Which one do you want to use? A shell script or a Python's structure to hold a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be holding information in a list structure `[..]` which is quite synonymous to a construct in Python which is *not* readily implemented in `bash` (which has arrays) or `Awk`.

You can simply do the following

```
import json
str='date |v3| 0.00| 0.00| 0.00| 0| 0| 7324.00| 0.00| 12278 12276|Tue Jan 29 09:36:47'
split_str = str.split("|")
wo_spaces = [ str.strip() for str in split_str ]
print( json.dumps( wo_spaces ) )
["date", "v3", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0", "0", "7324.00", "0.00", "12278 12276", "Tue Jan 29 09:36:47"]
```

Answer (score 3):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1="\",\"" -v s2="\"" '{gsub(/\|/,s1);$0="[" s2 $0 s2 "]"} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
["date ","v3"," 0.00"," 0.00"," 0.00"," 0"," 0"," 7324.00"," 0.00"," 12278 12276","Tue Jan 29 09:36:47"]
```

***2nd Solution:*** OR to deal with uneven spaces try following.

```
awk -v s1="\",\"" -v s2="\"" -v s3="\" ,\"" '{gsub(/ \||\| /,s3);gsub(/\|/,s1);$0="[" s2 $0 s2 "]"} 1' Input_file
```

OR(a non-one liner form of above):

```
awk -v s1="\",\"" -v s2="\"" -v s3="\" ,\"" '
{
  gsub(/ \||\| /,s3)
  gsub(/\|/,s1)
  $0="[" s2 $0 s2 "]"
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
["date" ,"v3" ,"0.00" ,"0.00" ,"0.00" ,"0" ,"0" ,"7324.00" ,"0.00" ,"12278 12276","Tue Jan 29 09:36:47"]
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy `sed` way:

```
sed 's/\s*|\s*/","/g;s/^/["/;s/$/"]/'
```

Output:

```
["date","v3","0.00","0.00","0.00","0","0","7324.00","0.00","12278 12276","Tue Jan 29 09:36:47"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ export a='date |v3| 0.00| 0.00| 0.00| 0| 0| 7324.00| 0.00| 12278 12276|Tue Jan 29 09:36:47'
$ echo $a | perl -F"\s*\|\s*" -lane ' $_="\x22".$_."\x22" for(@F); print "[",join(",",@F),"]" '
["date","v3","0.00","0.00","0.00","0","0","7324.00","0.00","12278 12276","Tue Jan 29 09:36:47"]
$
```